# If $X_i, i = 1, 2, 3$, are independent exponential random variables with rates $λ_i,\ i = 1, 2, 3$, find $E[maxX_i|X_1<X_2<X_3]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is a textbook question but it's for independent study.

Q:If $X_i, i = 1, 2, 3$, are independent exponential random variables with rates $λ_i,\ i = 1, 2, 3$, find $E[maxX_i|X_1<X_2<X_3]$.

Ans.

$E[maxX_i|X_1<X_2<X_3]$

$=E[X_1 + (X_2-X_1)+(X_3-X_2)|X_1<X_2<X_3]$

$=E[X_1|X_1<X_2<X_3]+E[(X_1-X_2)|X_1<X_2<X_3]+E[(X_3-X_2)|X_1<X_2<X_3]$

$=\dots=$ Answers

I don't understand why are we substracting $(X_2-X_1)$, this will make $X_1$ to be the maximum and we have already calulate it in this first part $\rightarrow E[X_1|X_1<X_2<X_3]$.

Edit:
$=E[X_1 + (X_2-X_1)+(X_3-X_3)|X_1<X_2<X_3]$ into $=E[X_1 + (X_2-X_1)+(X_3-X_2)|X_1<X_2<X_3]$

Comment: What does max$X_i$ mean in $E[max X_i | X_1<X_2<X_3]$? If $X_3$ is stated to be the largest, how is max $X_i$ different from $X_3$, given the condition ?

Comment: $X_1$ is not the maximum, $X_3$ is, given by what you are conditioning on. It should be $E(X_1 + (X_2 - X_1) + (X_3 - X_2)\vert X_1 < X_2 < X_3).$

Comment: So how does the equation $[_1+(_2−_1)+(_3−_2)|1<2<3] $ related to the maximum?

Comment: Because $X_3 = X_1 + (X_2-X_1)+(X_3-X_2):$ it's just arithmetic.

Comment: if we know the $max(X_i) = X_3$, can't we just simply calculate $[X_3|1<2<3] $?